# JDBCTemplate.queryForList does not work for Spring Boot v1.5.9

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

After upgrade Spring Boot from version 1.3.3 to 1.5.9, the JDBCTemplate.queryForList does not work properly. Before(version 1.3.3) the query can return the result, now(version 1.5.9) only the empty list. Can someone help me out?

---

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private static final String CSZH_START_DATE_SQL = "select distinct month from rpt.rpt_cszh_rgst_rnk_city_monthly";

List<Map<String, Object>> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql);
```

---